# Show data on datatables using laravel Ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel, datatables

I want to get data from the database using ajax in laravel.

I have A jquery datatable without `<table>, <td> and <tr> tags`.

So I'm trying the following code :

My blade :

```
<!--  Table ------>

    <div class="card d-flex flex-row mb-3 datatableRows">
                    <a class="d-flex" href="">
                                 <img src="" alt="Goose Breast"
                            class="list-thumbnail responsive border-0 card-img-left" />
                    </a>
                    <div class="pl-2 d-flex flex-grow-1 min-width-zero">
                        <div
                            class="card-body align-self-center d-flex flex-column flex-lg-row justify-content-between min-width-zero align-items-lg-center">
                          
                            <p class="list-item-heading mb-0 truncate"></p>
                            
                            <p class="mb-0 text-muted text-small w-15 w-sm-100"></p>
                            <p class="mb-0 text-muted text-small w-15 w-sm-100"></p>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

<!---- End Table ---------->

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

 $('#datatableRows').DataTable({
  processing: true,
  serverSide: true,
  ajax:{
   url: "{{ route('castingss.getdata') }}",
  },
  columns:[
  
   {
    data: 'casting_photo',
    name: 'casting_photo',
    render: function(data, type, full, meta){
                     return "<img src={{ URL::to('/') }}/castingimages/" + data + " class='list-thumbnail responsive border-0 card-img-left' />";
    },
    orderable: false
   },
   {
    data: 'casting_cin',
    name: 'casting_cin'
   },
    {
    data: 'casting_phone',
    name: 'casting_phone'
   },
    {
    data: 'casting_sexe',
    name: 'casting_sexe'
   },
   
   {
    data: 'action',
    name: 'action',
    orderable: false
   }
  ]
 });
 });
</script>
```

My Controller :

```
  function getdata(Request $request)
    {
        if(request()->ajax())
        {
            return datatables()->of(Casting::latest()->get())
                    ->addColumn('action', function($data){
                        $button = '<button type="button" name="edit" id="'.$data->id.'" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</button>';
                        $button .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                        $button .= '<button type="button" name="delete" id="'.$data->id.'" class="delete btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>';
                        return $button;
                    })
                    ->rawColumns(['action'])
                    ->make(true);
        }
       return view('Casting.castingss');

    }
```

when I execute it does not show me the data.

When I update my datatable to a datatable with `<table>` tag and attribute an `id` to the table, it works

If you have any idea, help me

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can check your browser console (F12) for error messages, and [edit] your question to provide the error information (as formatted text).

Comment: Show us the raw text of the JSON data sent from Laravel to the browser - [edit] your question and add in the JSON data.